# SMS/MMS database location?

Tags: sms

I'm trying to pull SMS messages from an old Nandroid backup, but need to find the database before I can. I found an article listing its location in Kitkat, but can't find anything for Nougat/Oreo. (Or even Marshmallow for that matter.)

Anyone happen to know where the files for SMS/MMS messages are actually stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While for Android 6 and 7 the DB with SMS data is located under

> /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony

on my LineageOS 15 (Oreo) the file has been moved under

> /data/data/com.android.messaging

and renamed to bugle_db

Oo

Answer (score 1):

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

Comment: Thank you!  (Although on my Oreo phone it's actually mmssms.db)  I just couldn't track it down, for some reason even FIND wasn't finding any DB containing 'sms' in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mokee rom this is the location:-
data/data/com.android.messaging/databases/bugle_db
Copy it using some root file browser(ES explorer/Amaze file manager) and rename it to bugle_db.db

Comment: I am sorry, this doens't really answer the question. You didn't specify which Version of Android the Mokee rom is based on. He specifially asked for the location of the sms database on recent Android version. Since the question it has been asked about 9 months ago I doubt it's even still revelant.

Comment: Mokee rom has many version(Marshmallow to Oreo), I am personally using Nougat and path of the database given above, it may help somebody